# how to use sox in google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, sox, audeering-opensmile

I trying to use openSMILE in google cloud functions, but I have a problem.

openSMILE seems to depend on the sox library. So I added sox to google cloud functions requirements.txt.

However, only the same log is being repeated.

"SoX could not be found!"

How can I fix this?

I use google cloud functions based on python3.7 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [sox py documentation](https://pypi.org/project/sox/) you can see that it also:

> Requires that SoX version 14.4.2 or higher is installed.

Which is basically a client that cannot be installed in a requirement.txt as a library. As you can see on this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50436340/12857703), which is about npm, but also applies to py:

> If you provide your own Linux-compiled binary, you may be able to execute it directly.

So you are going to have to get a compiled Sox Library, deploy it alongside your Cloud Function and start it every time the function is triggered.

Comment: First, thank you so much for your answer.
I think your solution way too far from my level.
I can't even understand it :(
So, for now, I decided not to use that feature in GCP Functions.